# JavaScript Key Press at Document Level

Tags: javascript, performance, keypress, onload

So we are thinking about doing something like the code below to prevent a new window from opening.

```
var onkeydown = function() { 
//alert(event.keyCode) 
if ((event.keyCode == 78) && (event.ctrlKey)) { 
    alert ("No new window") 
    event.cancelBubble = true; 
    event.returnValue = false; 
    event.keyCode = false; return false; 
}}
```

Our concern is that this block of code will get fired every time the user types a key, which makes sense.  The site requires a lot of typing and entering data.
Is this a big concern?  The block of code is small, but we were discussing that this could hinder performance? 
Is this something that we should be worried about or is the code above simple enough that we should be ok?

We don't need to worry about opening a new window from the menu because it hidden.

Comment: type and see for yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be a problem as it will normally not enter the if-statement. As long as you don't have any other key event listeners, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an eventhandler to listen for keypresses, and if the keys you pressed just so happen to be ctrl + n, you should use event.preventDefault to make sure it doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
   var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
      if(code == 78 && code == 17) { //ctrl + n
         e.preventDefault();
        alert("no new window");
        //further actions
   }
});
```

This listens if a key is down, then checks whether the keys you pressed are ctrl and N,
if so it prevents doing the default action and proceeds doing whatever you put inside the function.